# How to search for a string in an array, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an variable like:

```
var d;
d = [{'category': 'Hourly Report','from_start_datetime': '2013','format': 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss', 'id': 'dateRangeTo'}]
```

when I write `console.log(d[0])` it shows me `[`, but I want it to show me the dictionary I have in this variable. But when I place it in an array, it looks like:

```
dd = ['[{'category': 'Hourly Report','from_start_datetime': '2013','format': 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss', 'id': 'dateRangeTo'}]']
```

But what I actually want is the dictionary, and secondly I want to get the value of `category` in the dictionary.
please give me some hints.

Comment: console.log(d['category'])

Comment: @harsha: nothing happened!!!! by console.log(d['category']), its showing `undefined`

Comment: SO isn't for "hints".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yeah and its not also for degrading anyone, its for helping others. If one can't help, he may not degrade or taunt  others. Thanks

Comment: @MHS: You're right! Which is why I neither "degraded" nor "taunted" you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sorry if you mind! :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about this (as I can't post the code as I want as a comment)

```
var array_of_objects = [
    {'a': 'b'},
    {'a': 'c'}
];
array_of_objects;         // Array  [{a: "b"}, {a: "c"}]
array_of_objects[0];      // Object {a: "b"}
array_of_objects[0]['a']; // String "b"
```